# How to use Logger in your flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use logger package provided by dart in my build method
**Implementation of logger**
I create a file at the top of the tree called constants.dart
**constants.dart**

```
    import 'package:logger/logger.dart';


var logger = Logger(
    printer: PrettyPrinter(
  methodCount: 0,
  errorMethodCount: 5,
  lineLength: 50,
  colors: true,
  printEmojis: true,
  printTime: true,
));
```

I Just import this file then I can use it
**PROBLEM**

- I am only able to use                      `logger.d(_imageUrl);` in the state class not in my build method

**ERROR WHEN USING IN BUILD**

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Edit Products'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _saveFormKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  initialValue: _initValues['title'],
                  logger.d('_imageUrl');
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  validator: (value) {
```

This is how I use it in the build Inside TEXTFORMFIELD

**ERROR MESSAGE**

> Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. Try removing
> the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named
> arguments.
>
> Positional arguments must occur before named arguments. Try moving all
> of the positional arguments before the named arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You can't put a random function in the middle of the constructor of a `TextFormField`, or any constructor that doesn't take a Function as a parameter (like an `onPressed` for example).

```
 TextButton(
      child: Text('Button'),
      onPressed: () {
        logger.d('_imageUrl'); // this would be valid
      },
    )
```

If you want that in your build method just put it right above your return statement.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  logger.d('_imageUrl');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Edit Products'),
      ),
...
```

## Edit

I forgot that `TextFormField` has a few functions in the constructor. So you could also do something like this.

```
TextFormField(
      onTap: () => logger.d('_imageUrl'),
      onChanged: (text) => logger.d(text),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, it worked though it is sad to hear that we cannot add it in the place where we need it. but for now, it will do... thank you

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

@Loren.A  already describe the situation with solutions. If you like to get immediate value/perform operation before widget, you can use inline function in this case.

```dart
(){ 
/// do some stuff, but don't make it heavy operation
return MyWidget(..);
}(),
```

In your case

```dart
() {
  logger.d('_imageUrl');
  return TextFormField(...);
}(),
```